# How to add text between items in a array for my discord bot! discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

My goal it add text between each image inside of the array below! The bot is functional inside of discord but it would be nice to be able to add info about each image above it.

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

message.channel.send ("Niobe labs map colors signify which weapon to use!",{files: ["./destiny/Niobe labs/map 1.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/entrance.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/map 2.jpg",
    "./destiny/Niobe labs/map 3.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/map 4.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/map 5.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/map 6.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/map 7.jpg","./destiny/Niobe labs/map 8.jpg"]});

}

module.exports.help = {
      name: "niobelabs"
  }
```

Comment: You can't do it easily. The only way is to send several messages (one for each image, with text and file) instead of one...

Comment: So i did that earlier but when uploading to discord it uploads the images out of order! Which is not intended. There guide images so they need to be in order. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: The images are placed in order as they are in the array. If this is not working for you, then you may want to send each image as a different message in order to place them correctly.

Comment: To ensure order is correct when sending multiple messages await the promise returned by channel.send()